# Is there a better way to say "young adult" than 若い大人？

Tags: words

I have this feeling that 若い大人 is too much of a direct translation and kind of unnatural but I have no idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about 「[若年]{じゃくねん}[成人]{せいじん}」, though this sounds a bit more literary.

According to [Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%82%A2%E3%83%80%E3%83%AB%E3%83%88), it looks like 「ヤングアダルト」 is also used, but I think it's usually used in the context of literary genres.

I think you could also use [青年]{せいねん}, depending on the context.

Comment: I went for 大人になりつつある人 because it fit my context best but yeah there's no mistake going with ヤングアダルト!

Comment: @galki What context are you using it in? And, about how old would "young adult" usually be?

Comment: 「赤ちゃんは話そうとする。子供は分かろうとする。そして大人になりつつある人は精神的に成長しようとする。」って文脈。今回は大人と区別したかったです。年は18-25ぐらいですね。

Comment: @galki そういう感じでしたら、「青年」がいいと思います。「青年」は、幅もありますが、だいたいこんな感じみたいです。https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9D%92%E5%B9%B4 / http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1324533408 / http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/122486/meaning/m0u/%E9%9D%92%E5%B9%B4%E6%9C%9F/

Comment: なるほど！ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you don't want to use 若い大人... you can also use the following:

[男子]{だんし}[大人]{おとな}, [少年]{しょうねん}[大人]{おとな}, [青年]{せいねん}[大人]{おとな} which all means young adult man/boy.

[少女]{しょうじょ}[成人]{せいじん} which means young adult woman/girl.

I hope this help answer your question. (^^)

Comment: None of the words you suggested is listed in the Balanced Corpus of Contemporary Written Japanese (containing about 100m words). Even rare words will usually have several hits. There doesn't seem to be any evidence that these words are actually used...

Comment: they're combining two words into one so it would make sense that you wouldn't see them if you just copy pasted them into the corpus

Comment: @frei I saw that they're combining two words into one. But still the question remains: are they actually used in this combination or not? The data suggests not. This answer, however, suggests to use them...

Comment: you're right, and as you say a brief search suggests they're not used at all, so no idea how this poster arrived at this answer